# Save an audio file into a specific folder in android

Tags: android, record, voice

Well, first of all I'm new on android development and I'm learning by myself. I followed some tutorials to make an audio recorder app. But in these tutorials saves the recorded files in the path /sdcard. I want that my app saves to another location. For example in /sdcard/Voice path (Voice folder is not created). How is the simplest way to do it? I searched a lot and I can't find any answer.

My code (Please undestand that my native language is spanish so a few methods are in spanish)

```
public class FragmentRecording extends Fragment {
private MediaRecorder recorder;
private String OUTPUT_FILE;
FloatingActionButton stop_fab;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recording, container,false);
    stop_fab=(FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.stop_fab_xml);
    //SALIDA DEL ARCHIVO
    OUTPUT_FILE=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/VoiceRecorder.3gpp";

    //GENERAMOS UN METODO PARA SABER LIBERAR EL MICROFONO
    LiberarMicro();
    //Crea el archivo
    File outfile=new File(OUTPUT_FILE);
    //Si existe lo borra
    if(outfile.exists()){
        outfile.delete();
    }
    //Empieza Proceso de Grabacion
    try {
        StartRecord();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    stop_fab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            StopRecord();
        }

    });


    return view;}



protected void StopRecord() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(recorder!=null){
        recorder.stop();
    }
}



private void StartRecord() throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    recorder=new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);

    recorder.prepare();

    recorder.start();
}

private void LiberarMicro() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(recorder!=null){
            recorder.release();
        }

}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/somedir");
if(f.isDirectory()) {
        //Write code for the folder exist condition

}else{

        // create a File object for the parent directory
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/");
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
       // create a File object for the output file
       File outputFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory, filename);
       // now attach the OutputStream to the file object, instead of a String representation
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

}
```

> The above code will check wheather a folder exist or not. If not create a folder and save file to that folder.

You will need to provide the permission below in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

let me know if you are confused. kindly vote Up if i helped :) Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
  SDCardpath = getFilesDir();
    myDataPath = new File(SDCardpath.getAbsolutePath()
            + "/.My Recordings");

    // mydir = context.getDir("media", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!myDataPath.exists())
        myDataPath.mkdir();


    audiofile = new File(myDataPath + "/" + fileName);

                     OR
```

give storage permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Use this for the path to sd card

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File storagePath = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/folderName");
File yourfile= new File(storagePath + "/" + fileName + ".filetype");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add /Voice to your OUTPUT_FILE first. Then add following code:

```
 if (!outfile.getParentFile().exists())
    outfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code too.

```
   boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
     if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}
```

it allow to make a path in sd card or you can follow the complete [tutorial](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/06/hi-guys-now-i-want-to-show-you-how-to.html).